# Center icons and spread them on multiple lines automatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make a launch bar in my application with a number of icons.

Is there a way for the icons to be automatically distributed on multiple lines if a line is full?

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/MenuLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:gravity="center">
</LinearLayout>
```

With this code they overflow out of the screen. Any idea?

Comment: By "launch bar" I mean a number of ImageButtons at the bottom of the screen giving access to my app's features. Kinf of like the dashboard pattern (http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/02/ui-design-pattern-dashboard.html) but with only a few lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will not in the end implement such a menu, but rather display a much icons as we can and provide a "more" button if needed.

However if someone is looking for something similar in the future, [this DashboardLayout](https://gist.github.com/882650) would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I think the term you are looking is Menu Options.

Link to assist you with creating menu
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Fairly straightforward
You need to

1. Create a menu xml in menu folder
2. Inflate the menu in onCreateOptionsMenu of your activity
3. Control menu action (eg. open activity) in onOptionsItemSelected of your activity

Comment: That's not what I mean, what I want is an icon bar displayed on the Activity and not in top of it. But the behavior implemented in the Menu Options is what I'm looking for - automatic arrangement of fixed-size items depending on available space.